# Error at login in Asp .Net and MySQL

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am trying to connect to a database on an sql server in asp .net.
Here is a part of the code:

```
try
            {
                connection = new SqlConnection();
                if(connection != null)
                    try
                    {
                        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1,3306;Initial Catalog=MyPlace;User ID=root;Password=student";
                        connection.Open();
                        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
                        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            String s1 = (String)rdr["id"];
                            Response.Redirect(s1);
                            // Operate on fetched data
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc) { Response.Output.Write(exc.Message); }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Output.Write(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                    cmd.Dispose();
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.Close();
                if (rdr != null)
                    rdr.Dispose();
            }
```

The error I receive is : 
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider:TCP Provider, error:0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Any ideas why this might happen? I've already gone through the basic troubleshooting steps, but nothing seems to help...

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of things but start with the simplest which would be to verify that your MySql database is allowing connections.  yes it seems silly, but we recently ran in to a case where an application wasn't behaving and part of the problem was the way the MySql users were configured which limited where they could connect from and what they could do once connected.

Assuming you can connect locally through the sql tools, and since you are running on the default port try this connect string instead of the one you are using

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Also make sure there aren't any conflicts with the MySql connectors on your box.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried that and the new error is : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Actually the error above was because I removed 3306 port from connection string. The error that shows up now is : Non-negative number required. Parameter name: count. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well the good news is that you are connecting to the database.   The issue now is related to your sql string.  Have you tested just running the sql statement on the db to make sure you get the expected return?